# Best practices - How should one go about drawing lots of rectangular (=similar) shapes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices

This is rather general inquiry, with intent to find out how to go about this the best way with the less time-consuming the better. How would you draw a graphics with lots of rectangles (or other similar forms) with TikZ?

- Would you make each bit a node?
- Would you use some advanced node positioning methods, or maybe use a matrix?

Little explanation for the example below: it's a sketch of a lab machine. There are obviously lots of rectangular shapes and nearly equally many nodes "pointing" to them. On the right of the nodes (and currently not visible) are the same rectangular shapes, just rotated by 90°, in the sense of a sectional drawing.

[image: picture]

### MWE 01 (picture below), first attempt

```
\documentclass[
11pt,
a4paper
]
{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    setspace,
    hyperref
}

\usetikzlibrary{
    external,
    calc,
    matrix,
    fit,
    positioning,
    calc
}

\tikzset{
descr/.style={
draw,
rectangle,
text width=3.5cm,
minimum height=1cm, %use this because text width makes the text bottom-aligned
align=center}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
%the following foreach loop would obviously increase the speed of drawing the shapes on the left, but it is, as far as I can see, entirely without any coherent content -> a foreach loop is unfortunately of no use, also because of different lengths and heights
%\foreach \y in {0,2,4,6,8}{
%\node[draw, rectangle, text width=5cm, text height=1cm, align=center] at (0,\y) {aaa};}
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=4cm, text height=1.5cm, align=center] (node01) at (0,2) {node1};
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=4cm, text height=2cm, align=center] (node02) at (0,4) {node2};
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=5cm, text height=1.5cm, align=center] (node03) at (0,6) {node3};
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=3cm, text height=1.5cm, align=center] (node04) at (0,8) {node4};
\node[draw, rectangle, text width=4cm, text height=1.5cm, align=center] (node05) at (0,10) {node5};
%
%the 'descriptive' nodes on the right can be placed in this matter and the loop enables a somewhat uniform 'descriptive' look
%but with using a loop, I am clueless as to how I can name each node then
\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\foreach \x/\y in {{Stuff and lots of other words}/0,Word/2,Text/4,aaa/6,bbb/8}{
    \node[descr] at (0,\y) {\x};}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Picture for MWE 01

[image]

Comment: This is a question, which tend to be closed because it is too broad...

Comment: TikZ has a `pin` similar to `label`. You can add `draw` option to it.

Comment: @percusse Thank your for your reply. So one way would be I make each one a `node`, and add a minimum height and width? (Please confirm or deny. :)) Considering I'd like the nodes on the right more or less aligned horizontally on top of each other, I think I am not making them pins.

Comment: It's much simpler if you make a MWE so people can offer different solutions. Otherwise this is bound to have misunderstandings and updates

Comment: There is no *general* answer, I don't think, beyond 'it depends'. It depends on the diagram and on what you (or we) know how to do! For example, I'm working on a timeline at the moment and right now, I've placed some nodes using `\foreach` loops and some manually. I am using some commands to automate some of the placement and to reduce typing but I'm not using entirely the same strategy even for different parts of the same diagram...

Comment: @percusse Added an MWE.

Comment: @cfr You are right. It all is very theoretical/conceptual. Added an MWE, btw.

Comment: In addition to absolute coordinates, you can use relative coordinates and things like [above] and (node01.north).  Add the calc library and you can do things like ($(node01.east)!.333!(node01.west)$).

Comment: So what is the question exactly? That is, what don't you like about your current solution?

Comment: @JohnKormylo Thanks. Are you implying you'd place all nodes and drawings manually?

Comment: @henry - As opposed to a matrix?  Yes.  Using absolute coordinates?  No.

Comment: @cfr As I wrote before, the exact nature of my question was an inquire about something rather conceptual, and not something like "why should I make this node 3 cm wide instead of 2.5"? I like my solution, sort of, but I rather ask for other clues than not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if I could claim "best practices," but here is an alternative for part of the drawing shown at the top.  Note: the actual width and height of a node is the text width and height plus the inner sep.  Also, I threw out a lot of unused code simply because I am anal retentive.  The choice between lots of \draws or \nodes or lumping them together is purely esthetic.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small,thick]
\path
  (0,2) node[draw, text width=5cm, text height=2cm, inner sep=0pt] (node01) {}% mostly for the anshors
  (node01.south) node[above] {node1};% an easier way to align text to bottom, or top etc.
\draw
  ($(node01.west)!0.25!(node01.east)$) circle[radius=5mm]
  (node01.center) circle[radius=5mm]
  ($(node01.west)!0.75!(node01.east)$) circle[radius=5mm];
\path
  (node01.north) node[draw, above, text width=4cm, text height=1cm, inner sep=0pt] (node02) {}
  (node02.north) node[draw, above,  text width=1cm, text height=3cm, inner sep=0pt] (node03) {}
  (node03.north) node[draw, below, text width=2cm, text height=1cm, inner sep=0pt] (node04) {}
  (node04.center) node[draw, text width=7mm, text height=7mm, inner sep=0pt] (node05) {};
% Note: without the calc below the line would stop at (node03.north)
\draw[very thin, dash dot] (node01.south)+(0,-5mm) -- ($(node03.north)+(0,5mm)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: diagram]

As for loops, I have always felt that unless you NEED a loop, don't use one.  Partly this goes back to my Cray programming days, where a loop with less than 8 cycles is worse than repeating the code.